# Nginx subdomains with www

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I have Nginx configured in a Amazon EC2 server.

Right now both www.myserver.com, .myserver.com works perfect.

What I need, is configure www..myserver.com. I need to redirect the user to .myserver.com. I mean, I need to rewrite the url or something.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.myserver.com;
    return       301 http://myserver.com$request_uri;
}
```

You don't need "rewrites" in nginx. Leave them to apache, and read the docs:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html

**Upd:**

That is not clear from your question (who knows, what do you mean by double dots). But if you have ever tried to read the docs, you would easily modify the example for your needs:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  ~^www\.([^.]+\.myserver\.com)$;
    return       301 http://$1$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I dont have apache. Also this is not what I asked. I want www.mysubdomain.mysite.com be redirected to mysubdomain.mysite.com. Each user has a different random subdomain. Read the question.

Comment: he answered your question the serverblock he posted is what you add to your config to get the redirect you wanted. Go read the documentation he linked (especially the last one, what you want is covered there explicitly). Just change the `myserver.com` to match your domain.